# Automating enter key in Apple Script Editor

Tags: automation, applescript, automator

I'm using Discord and I need to be able to press the enter/return key ever 5.5 seconds, but it is tedious. How would I create a script to do this for me automatically? I tried using the script below, but it seems to mess Discord up and cause it to basically restart or go through the loading page again and again.

[AppleScript Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfG9p.png)

Could I create a script that would just hit the enter key on my keyboard and not directly interact with Discord? I guess with a delay of a few seconds after I run the script so i can select Discord and then the enter key being stroked will be in Discord. Is this possible? If so, could someone provide a basic script I could use?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
tell application "Discord" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    repeat 10 times
        keystroke return
        delay 5.5
    end repeat
end tell
```